# Install NodeJS without sudo for User without having home directory in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sudo

In my Ubuntu machine I have two users.

1. myuser - has home directory and password.
2. nohome - no home directory, no password.

I want to install nodejs for the user ***"nohome"*** without sudo.
I can install it for **myuser** in following way

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make install
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

It is working fine for that user. But I want to install for the other user or change owner ship to other user.

I tried following in **myuser**

```
sudo chown -R nohome:nohome ~/.npm
```

When I switch user to nohome and do **`which node`**, I get no result.

What is the best way to use node and npm for a user without using sudo?

Comment: FWIW, especially if you're installing from source, you do not need to install npm separately as it has been bundled with node for quite a long time now. Also if you installed io.js instead, installing a vanilla npm copy (currently) will break io.js because it floats patches on top of the built-in copy.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just need to knwo how can I use it for another user without `sudo`

Comment: Did you try just changing the group ownership (with appropriate group permissions) for the files and then just having both users be in the same group?

Comment: Also when you switch to `nohome`, are you sure that `$HOME/local` (`/home/myuser/local`) is in their `$PATH`?

Comment: @mscdex I tried only changing ownership of .npm directory to `nohome` user and group. How to change?

Comment: @mscdex `nohome` doesn't have a home directory and no .bashrc file. So it's not in their $PATH.